# Are batch updates/deletes/etc. possible with OneDrive's iOS (Or any) SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, onedrive

I have began implementing a OneDrive file manager of sort app. I work many other services, but for OneDrive it seems, according to documentation found at places such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659717.aspx, that it is not possible to do batch deletes, moves etc.

It appears if I want to, for example, delete or move 200 files, I will need to loop through and make 200 calls individually rather than being able to pass in an array of objects to be moved.

Anyone found a way to batch these requests?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no service supported batching with the LiveSDK.

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate the response! Would love to see this in the future as long moves/deletes/updates take a while =/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Its a great suggestion, Will!